# Geo redirect same domain after slash with AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-ec2, geolocation

Lets say i have a website called **abc.com**, I'm planning on scale the website based on geo location, I have two ways in mind.

The first way: **paris.abc.com, london.abc.com**

The second way: **abc.com/paris, abc.com/london**

The first way seems simpler with AWS, The idea being hosting different subdomains to different instances with different databases, Each subdomain is basically a completely different website.

But I prefer the second way, What i have in mind is, Setting up geo redirect to different instances but to the same domain, "abc.com", Then have instance A redirect abc.com to abc.com/paris inside my django project, Have instance B do the same thing to abc.com/london.

Now if i do it this way, What would happen if someone from london, Instead of typing the url abc.com, They typed abc.com/paris? Would they be able to access the paris page via instance A? (This is what i want, I want them to have acess) Or the page will be empty since the django project inside instances B(london) have no page called paris.

Assuming both ways are achievable, If someone logged in paris.abc.com or abc.com/paris, How do u keep them logged in If they go to page london.abc.com or abc.com/london afterwards, A shared database dedicated to store user infos but everything else is separated?

Finally, Is there a better and cleaner solution to achieve such goal with AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Host **paris.abc.com** **london.abc.com** in different EC2 instance. Use `ALB` with two target groups with those two instances. For storing user session use a single `Elasticache` where both Ec2 can get user session data.